# react-input-range library in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a `Range bar` like this

[image]

using `react-input-range`

but when writing this code

```
import InputRange from 'react-input-range';
import 'react-input-range/lib/css/index.css';

<form action="">
  <InputRange
      maxValue={100}
      minValue={0}
      formatLabel={value => `$${value}`}
      value={range}
      onChange={value => setRange(value)}
      onChangeComplete={value => console.log(value)}
    />
</form>
```

I got this

[image]

Comment: follow the documentation

Comment: I saw the documentation but not work for me and it was written using class based

Comment: what do you want, 2 breakpoints?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: you can find all examples here
https://codepen.io/lbauza20/embed/KqNMJa?default-tab=result&theme-id=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the initial value of range(state) and you are good to go.

```
const [range, setRange ]= useState({
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
      });
    <form action="">
      <InputRange
          maxValue={100}
          minValue={0}
          formatLabel={value => `$${value}`}
          value={range}
          onChange={value => setRange(value)}
          onChangeComplete={value => console.log(value)}
        />
    </form>
```